# light-locker: strange beheavior when trying to unlock the screen/open the lid

Tags: release-loki, greeter

loki has light-locker
I have setup that when I close the lid of the notebook the screen locks (not suspends)
when I close it and then after a while open it, I have to wait a few seconds to get rid of the annoying message saying
"you'll be redirected to the unlock dialog automatically in a few seconds"
[image: light-locker-message]

After it I get the normal lock screen where I can write the password down.
The sad thing is that after y pŕessed enter to submit the password I get the same black window message for a couple of seconds

Is there a way to disable this annoying black window to go straight to the lock screen?

I've only found this
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/light-locker-new-session-locker-for.html
thanks in advance